# Ошибка CS0103 в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```c
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float runSpeed = 500f;
    public float strafeSpeed = 500f;
    public float jumpForce = 15f;

    protected bool strafeLeft = false;
    protected bool strafeRight = false;
    protected bool doJump = false;
  
    void Update()
    {
     if(Input.GetKey("d"))   
     {
         strafeLeft = true; 
     } else
     {
         strafeLeft = false;
     }

     if(Input.GetKey("a")) 
     {
         strafeRight = true;
     } else
     {
         strafeRight = false;
     }
     if(Input.GetKey("space"))
     {
         doJump = true;
    }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
        if(strafeLeft)
        {
            rd.AddForce(-strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        
         if(strafeRight)
        {
            rd.AddForce(strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если 2D, то добавь: ```
void Start() { rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); }
``` И замени ```public Rigidbody rb;```
на ```public Rigidbody2D rb;```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Чтобы оставить комментарий, у вас должно быть 50 баллов репутации, а у меня их нет.

Comment: Assets\Plaer\Player.cs(48,13): error CS0103: The name 'rd' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Чего ты хочешь добиться строчкой ```rd.AddForce(-strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);```? Просто могу полностью переписать строку, да и скрипт так, чтобы работало.

Comment: текст ошибки? На какой строке?

Comment: Ошибка в имени переменной - вы AddForce делаете `rd`, когда переменная называется `rb`